# java hibernate could not extract ResultSet when trying to add entity

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I using oracle database and trying add new entity into "words" table.
My word model class:

```
@Entity(name = "Word")
public class Word implements Serializable{
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "etailerRaw_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "etailerRaw_seq",
            sequenceName = "'PRODUCT_ID_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "word")
    private Set<Translation> translations;

    public Set<Translation> getTranslations(){
        return  translations;
    }
}
```

translation modell class

```
@Entity(name = "Translation")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "etailerRaw_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "etailerRaw_seq",
            sequenceName = "'PRODUCT_ID_SEQ")
    private Long id;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Word getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setWord(Word word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getNameTranslation() {
        return nameTranslation;
    }

    public void setNameTranslation(String nameTranslation) {
        this.nameTranslation = nameTranslation;
    }

    public String getDescriptionTranslation() {
        return descriptionTranslation;
    }

    public void setDescriptionTranslation(String descriptionTranslation) {
        this.descriptionTranslation = descriptionTranslation;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Word_id", nullable = false)
    private Word word;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Lang_id", nullable = false)
    private Language language;

    private String nameTranslation;

    private String descriptionTranslation;



}
```

language model class

```
@Entity(name = "Language")
public class Language implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "etailerRaw_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "etailerRaw_seq",
            sequenceName = "'PRODUCT_ID_SEQ")
    private Long id;




    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "language")
    private Set<Translation> translations;

    public Set<Translation> getTranslations(){
        return  translations;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

word dao class

```
  public class WordDAOBean implements WordDAO {
    public void addWord(String description) {
        Word word=new Word();
        word.setName(description);
        Session session= HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.save(word);
        session.close();
    }

    public List<Word> getAllWords() {
        Session session= HibernateUtil.getSession();
        List<Word> words= session.createCriteria(Word.class).list();
        session.close();
        return  words;
    }
}
```

getAllWords method working successefull, but when i tryiing to add new word, i get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator$1.getNextValue(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at DAO.impl.WordDAOBean.addWord(WordDAOBean.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 76 more
]]
```

on this str session.save(word);

Comment: `sequenceName = "'PRODUCT_ID_SEQ"`. Notice the single quote at the beginning of the sequence name. Also, why are you defining the same sequence generator twice? Voting to close for simple typo error.

Answer (score 0):

sequenceName = "'PRODUCT_ID_SEQ". Notice the single quote at the beginning of the sequence name.  Thanks JB Nizet